# cannot print popup displaying pdf file

Tags: javascript, printing, popup

I have a php file with the following code:

```
<?php

?>
<form action="" id="f1" name="f1">
    <input type="button" name="preview" value="Open PDF" onclick="showPDF()" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showPDF(){
        var newwin=window.open("pdf.pdf","Window1","menubar=no,width=430,height=360,toolbar=no");
        newwin.print();      
    }
</script>
```

It opens  up a popup window with pdf file inside it BUT fails to open the print dialog box.
But the same code without the pdf filename i.e

```
var newwin=window.open("","Window1","menubar=no,width=430,height=360,toolbar=no");
```

opens up the popup window and show the print dialog box.

Can anybody provide me a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

does this work?

```
newwin.printWithDialog();
```